# Problems with scraping Tripadvisor with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, tripadvisor

I have this Python code for scraping the website TripAdvisor and until the last year (18 days ago) the code works awesome, but now the code doesn't work properly and I get this result (shown above)

I have bee trying with changes likes this  `container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='data-test-target']")`
But don't work. Also, I noted that now the website doesn't have the element `taLnk ulBlueLinks` or the element `review-container`.

Please, if you can help me with the code it will fantastic.

PD: Also, I was trying with beautiful soup but doesn't work the code anyway.

---

```
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

#Common
now = datetime.datetime.now()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
italia = "https://www.tripadvisor.it/Attraction_Review-g657290-d2213040-Reviews-Ex_Stabilimento_Florio_delle_Tonnare_di_Favignana_e_Formica-Isola_di_Favig.html"
driver.get(italia)

place = 'Ex_Stabilimento_Florio_delle_Tonnare_di_Favignana'
lang = 'it'


def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True





for i in range(0, 2):
    try:
        if (check_exists_by_xpath("//span[@class='taLnk ulBlueLinks']")):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='taLnk ulBlueLinks']").click()
            time.sleep(5)
        container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='review-container']")

        num_page_items = len(container)
        for j in range(num_page_items):

            csvFile = open(r'Italia_en.csv', 'a')
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

            time.sleep(10)
            rating_a = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(
                ".//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating bubble_')]").get_attribute("class")
            rating_b = rating_a.split("_")
            rating = rating_b[3]

            review = container[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//p[@class='partial_entry']").text.replace("\n", "")
            title = container[j].find_element_by_class_name('quote').find_element_by_tag_name(
                'a').find_element_by_class_name('noQuotes').text

            print(review)
            rating_date = container[j].find_element_by_class_name('ratingDate').get_attribute('title')
            print(rating, review, title, "--", sep='\n')
            link_list = []
            for link in container[j].find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
                link_previous = (link.get_attribute('href'))
                link_list.append(link_previous)

            print(link_list[1], "--", sep='\n')

            csvWriter.writerow([place, rating, title, review, rating_date, link_list[1], now, lang])

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"]').click()

        time.sleep(5)

    except:

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"]').click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

And the result is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gh_code2.py", line 63, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"]').click()
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gh_code2.py", line 69, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"]').click()
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.117)
```

Comment: It looks like the button your are searching for with xpath of `nav next taLnk ui_button primary` no longer exists. You must update your code to match the new page.

Comment: @IgnacioAguirre This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in my experience with scraping sites, if the site is updated and those xpath references are gone, you must update your script. In this case, it appears that

```
class="nav next taLnk ui_button primary"
```

Is no longer a viable selector. If this is a common reference, with similar structure over time, I would try and use iterations rather than an exact class name. i.e. nav button[0] or something of the like (dont have the exact syntax in front of me).

Otherwise, check out FireFox's selenium IDE browser. It can help you find other ways to reference items while clicking through the site.

Hope that is *some* help!